# Story about spaceship that has immutable digital archive of human knowledge

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to locate a short story that I read online a few months ago. It took place on a spaceship that contained a digital archive of all of human knowledge.

At some point, one of the characters made a grave error and overwrote some important mathematical constants, causing the ship to start making erroneous computations. They noticed that the time on their wrist watch was drifting away from the time on the ship's main computer. They noticed that the distances on the navigation chart didn't make sense anymore.

Comment: How could the "immutable" digital archive be overwritten?

Comment: @user14111 - Immutable-ish

Comment: @user14111 probably someone messed up with a file used for the spaceship's operation, but not related at all with the digital archive, which I understand should be more of a "cargo".

Comment: Immutable because they weren't supposed to edit it, not because the system actually prevented it.

Comment: Would love to have some actual, real-world immutable digital archives of history for people to study now...

Comment: Not the answer, but it reminds me of Stephen Donaldson's Gap series, where he goes into great detail about how it's physically impossible to rewrite datacores, only to reveal two books later that the aliens can do it (without explaining how).